# Scanner nextLine() doesn't work after System.in.read()

Tags: java

I have following code and am facing a problem if I use `System.in.read()` before `Scanner`.
Then the cursor moves at the end by skipping `nextLine()` function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InvoiceTest{
public static void main(String [] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter a Charater: ");
    char c = (char) System.in.read();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter id No...");
    String id_no = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Charater You entered "+ c +" Id No Entered "+ id_no);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't mix `System.in.read()` with `new Scanner(System.in)`. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

You are not consuming the newline character upon entering your character(`System.in.read()`) thus the `input.nextLine()` will consume it and skip it.

**solution:**

consume the new line character first before reading the input of for the id.

```
System.out.println("Enter a Charater: ");
    char c = (char) System.in.read();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter id No...");
    input.nextLine(); //will consume the new line character spit by System.in.read()
    String id_no = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Charater You entered "+c+" Id No Entered "+id_no);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

EJP comments thus:

> Don't mix System.in.read() with new Scanner(System.in). Use one or the other.

Good advice!

> So why is it a bad idea to mix reading from the stream and using `Scanner`?

Well, because `Scanner` operations will typically *read ahead* on the input stream, keeping unconsumed characters in an internal buffer.  So if you do a `Scanner` operation *followed* by a call to `read()` on the stream, there is a good chance that the `read()` will (in effect) skip over characters.  The behaviour is likely to be confusing and unpredictable ... and dependent on where the input characters are actually coming from.